# How to extract lines with different exit codes?

Tags: bash

Exit codes are logged separated by comma

The last 2 fields are exit code of 2 different versions of script

```
/opt/a/b/c,parameter,a b c,3,1
/opt/a/d/e,parameter,a b c,1,1
/opt/a/b/d,parameter,0,0
/opt/a/e/c,parameter,0,1
```

The exit code range from 0 to 20
How do I extract lines with different exit codes?

I am tired of doing:

```
cat log|grep -v ,0,0|grpe -v ,1,1|grep -v ,2,2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F , '$NF != $(NF-1)' log
```

Set the field separator (`FS`) to `,` with `-F ,`.
`NF` is the number of fields in the line.
`$NF` is the value of the last field on the line.
`$(NF-1)` is the value of the second to last field on the line.

`awk`'s default action is to print the line (i.e. `{print}`). So the awk script just needs to return a `truth-y` value when the last two fields differ. So we compare them.

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/,\([0-9]\+\),\1$/d' log
```

`d`elete any lines that match the pattern `,` followed by some number of digits (`[0-9]\+`) and capture that number (the `\(`/`\)` wrapping) then another `,` and the same number we already matched (`\1` for the first capture group). That leaves `sed` printing every other line (the ones that don't match).